# Find a word in a list of words that has minimum distance with a given word

Tags: python, nlp, linguistics, word-diff

let say given a word list `['windows','hello','python','world','software','desk']` and an input word `'widow'`, how to (quickly) find the word from the word list that has the minimum edit distance with the input word `'widow'` (The answer in this example is `'windows'`)? Are there available libraries/functions to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/#documentation) library. The `distance()` function is what you're looking for.

Regarding the list, I would do:

```
input = "widow"
words = ['windows','hello','python','world','software','desk']

distances = [distance(input, word) for word in words]
closest = words[distances.index(min(distances)]
```

You would have to handle the case where two words have the same distance for your input.

Answer (score 4):

Built-in `difflib`

```
import difflib
difflib.get_close_matches("widow", lst, n=1)

#out: ['windows']
```